# What are the ways DNX can find packages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I am contemplating using DNX for a new project, and can tell upfront that more than one shared library will be developed in the process of building the larger whole.

The DNX samples I've seen so far all resolve packages using NuGet, which is well and good, but what are the other ways packages can be retrieved? My projects won't be published to the public NuGet, so I need some other means of pulling dependencies. Git, file system, anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup an own nuget feed which is described on the nuget homepage:

http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

You also have the possiblity to add a folder as a source:

Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings:

[image]

Under Package Sources you can add a new entry pointing to a local ( or remote ) directory:

[image]

You still have the option use other options such as including binaries in a Lib folder, adding GIT repositories as submodules and even including source files using something like [https://github.com/mrange/T4Include](https://github.com/mrange/T4Include%20T4Include). Those options have different advantages and disadvantages and without being involved in a project a decision can't be made.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular alternative to NuGet and the one that we, the ASP.NET team, use is [MyGet](https://myget.org). You can create public or private MyGet feeds where you can store your packages. This also allows you to do branched development by having multiple feeds. For example: one for development, one for staging and one for production.

The other approach, which might require more infrastructure, is a file share. The con for this is that you need everyone on the same network so they can access the share.